# How do you change the colors of the Oracle Apex Date Picker?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an issue with the Oracle Apex Date Picker. I have the Vita - Dark theme enabled in my app and this is how the drop-downs of the Date Picker look by default:

[image]   [image]

None of the options are visible because both the background color and the text color are white. How do I change the background color on these drop-downs?

Comment: Works fine for me on apex 22.2. What version of apex are you on ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie are you using the Vita - Dark theme? Or any other Dark theme? That's where the issue is. Also I'm using the cloud version of Apex so it's always the latest version.

Comment: Yes, apex 22.2 with Vita Dark theme just as you described. You didn't answer my question...

Comment: I'm on version 22.2.1. May I see a screenshot please?

Comment: @KoenLostrie or maybe there's a way to downgrade the cloud version of Apex?

Comment: Don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me. Here is an application on 22.2 with Vita Dark theme:

[image]

This is how I would debug. Create a new app from scratch with just the date picker, see if that works fine and if it does check what the differences are with your app.

I would start by refreshing the universal theme, that is a step that should be done as part of the upgrade. Google "oracle apex refresh universal theme". If the theme is out of sync with the version of apex this could cause UI issues.

Comment: Tried it with a new app and getting the same exact issue. Actually I notice that your dropdown looks very different to mine. Did you change it or is it like this by default?

Comment: I'm using the Chrome browser. I tried it on a Firefox browser instead and it looks slightly different but still problematic: https://i.ibb.co/5WhH27G/Untitled.png

Comment: Suspect this isn't browser related. Check my update about theme refresh

Comment: I refreshed the theme using these instructions: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut211/updating-universal-theme but still having the same issue.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, but I'm pretty sure this is related to the universal theme

Comment: Is there a way to change the background color using the theme roller? Or maybe by adding a CSS class?

Comment: there has to be something in CSS I can add to change the background color? I have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: I'm sorry can't help you with that. As I said, I'd check the universal theme upgrade again. Search forums on how to do that and on how to verify the upgrade was successful

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the following lines to Custom CSS attribute on the theme roller. Feel free to change the color.

```
div.a-DatePicker-month > select,
div.a-DatePicker-year > select {
  background-color:grey;
}
```